# Using Iterator error

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I'm using following method below, that will provide me count how many cars have rear wheel drive. The Array List stores it as a boolean.

When I try to compile get error that cannot find symbol - variable getIsRearWheelDrive.I have this method in my Lamborghini class.

```
public int howManyAreRearWheelDrive()
    {
        int i = 0;
        Iterator<Lamborghini> rear = inventory.iterator();
        while(rear.hasNext()){
            Lamborghini nextLamb = rear.next();
            if(nextLamb.getIsRearWheelDrive.equals(true))
            {               
                int rearHold = nextLamb.getIsRearWheelDrive();
                i++;
            }  
            return rearHold;
        }

Lamborghini class
public boolean getIsRearWheelDrive()
    {
        return isRearWheelDrive;
    }
```

Comment: use  if(nextLamb.getIsRearWheelDrive().equals(true)) . You forgot to add () (functional brackets) to method. getIsRearWheelDrive is not a variable but function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have plenty of errors in this code, I will add comments to it

```
public int howManyAreRearWheelDrive()
{
    int i = 0;
    Iterator<Lamborghini> rear = inventory.iterator();
    while(rear.hasNext()){
        Lamborghini nextLamb = rear.next();

        if(nextLamb.getIsRearWheelDrive ()) // this is a method .equals(true))

        {               
            // int rearHold = nextLamb.getIsRearWheelDrive();
            // why cast this to an local int??
            i++;
        }  
        // return rearHold;
        // readHold is not in scope here
        // if you return here, the while loop will not complete
        // the variable i is hold the value you want
    }

//Lamborghini class
public boolean getIsRearWheelDrive()
{
    return isRearWheelDrive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
 if(nextLamb.getIsRearWheelDrive.equals(true))
```

With this line:

```
 if(nextLamb.getIsRearWheelDrive())
```

Because the method `getIsRearWheelDrive()` return a boolean.
And create the variable `isRearWheelDrive`